# Margin doesn't Effect Element's Position

Tags: html, css

**Problem:**

Why doesn't .locmidcontent position the set of element (form)?

**Here is my HTML structure:**

```
    <div class="locmidcontent">
        <form action="#" method="GET">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label>Country</label>
                    <select>
                         <option>ABC</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Region</label>
                    <select>
                         <option>XYZ</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>City</label>
                    <select>
                         <option>COM</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input value="View" type="submit">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**My CSS:**

```
.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

/* DOESN'T WORK */
.locmindcontent {
        margin-right: 200px;
        margin-top: 200px;
}

.locmidcontent ul li{
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

**Snapshot - The current position is the default one, i need to move it to the arrow directions**

[image]

Comment: try floating the wrapping div ( or maybe the form )

Comment: I decide to close/delete it since its not a real question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the fact that it says `.locmindcontent` instead of `.locmidcontent` in your CSS Change the name and try again.

Comment: This was the first answer by a total of seven seconds.  @user311509 can you please select this as the correct answer in order to close out this question?

Answer (score 2):

You misspelled `.locmindcontent`, it should be `.locmidcontent`.